# Redrawing a view in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible to redraw the whole view.

I need it to complete my language settings. The problem is that the language only changes after the views there drawn again. Like you go out of settings and then go in again, then the language is changed. But the moment you save everything, the language stays the same.

So how should i redraw my views, or by best the whole app, after the language change was found?

Comment: in your viewController [self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];

Comment: Just curious - why don't you use the standard "automatic" language selection by iOS? Personally, I think language selection in iOS apps is a pain and usually a clear sign of "I don't care" programming style.

Comment: And what is standart "automatic" language selection. I'v implemented my language selection based on one of the examples in internet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ARC:

```
- (void)setLanguage:(LanguageType)languageType
{
    _language = languageType;

    //TODO:your settings

    [_theWholeView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If that can not work , there is a very troublesome solution , it can reload the whole view.

You can code like this:
In the view.h , you need creat a delegate.
@protocol WholeViewDelegate

```
- (void)reloadData;
```

@end

In the view.m

```
- (void)setLanguage:(LanguageType)languageType
{
    _language = languageType;

    //TODO:your settings

    [_delegate reloadData];
}
```

In the controller you need to implement the delegate
In the controller.m

```
- (void)reloadData
{
    if(_wholeView)
    {
        [_wholeView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    // in the wholeView init method you should refresh your data
    _wholeView = [[WholeView alloc] init];
    self.view addSubview:_wholeView
}
```

Comment: Still can't get it done. Works the same.. :( I'v managed to get it incompletely done using [tableview reloadData] but that doesn't update my dynamicly created tablerows.. Hmm how do you select the whole app view ? self.view doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Call `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay)).

Comment: If you have changes pending and want to tell the view to redraw, I think this is what you need. Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just call setNeedsDisplay.. It will resolve the problem. setNeedsDisplay actually calls the drawRect function in the UIView class by passing the frame of the view as the rectangular parameter. Hope that helps....

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help. It doesn't redraw the titles of the cell using this method

Comment: if u r trying to rename a button or label u can straightaway change its text or title to another string. for label we have `myLabel.text = @"Mytext";

Comment: Yes i know that as well. I'm trying to update tableview which has values stored in Mutablearray. And i need my Array to get new values without initializing them over and over again, the objects in array are LocalizedStrings, so the user may change which localizedstrings to use for tableview.

Comment: use replaceObjectAtIndex object method for replacing strings in the mutable array. Hope that helps....