# Timer not counting down correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timer, nstimer

So I have a timer that gets an `NSTimeInterval` from a task which the user inputs. The timer uses the NSDateComponents class to separate the timeinterval into a `HH:MM:SS` format. For some reason, my label (which has the `HH:MM:SS` format) is not updated each time the timer selector is sent. I know the selector works because every second the `NSLog` message gets sent, but the label is not updated. Any ideas why?

**TimerViewController.h**

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar;
    NSDateComponents *components;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLeft;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Tasks *testTask;
@property NSTimer *timer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *now;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date1;
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t;
@end
```

---

**TimerViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
    self.date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[testTask timeInterval] sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
}
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t{
   NSDateFormatter *timerFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [timerFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
     NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit  fromDate:now toDate:self.date1 options:0];

    NSString *timeRemaining = nil;
    if([now compare:self.date1] == NSOrderedAscending){
        timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]];
        NSLog(@"works %@", timeRemaining);
    } else {
        timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00:00"];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        NSLog(@"ended");
    }
   timerLabel.text = timeRemaining;
    [timerLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

---

**Error message:**

```
*** -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: toDate cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil toDate?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x015bdc78 -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:] + 200
    1   ToDoTasks                           0x0000980b -[DetailViewController timerAction:] + 299
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0160bff6 -[__NSCFTimer fire] + 150
    3   ToDoTasks                           0x00009393 -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad] + 435
    4   UIKit                               0x002e11c7 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 536
    5   UIKit                               0x002e1232 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    6   UIKit                               0x002e14da -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 36
    7   UIKit                               0x002f88e5 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 36
    8   UIKit                               0x002f89cb -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    9   UIKit                               0x002f8c76 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 254
    10  UIKit                               0x002f8d71 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 72
    11  UIKit                               0x002f989b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    12  UIKit                               0x002f9e93 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1030
    13  UIKit                               0x002f9a88 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    14  ToDoTasks                           0x00006acf -[ToDoTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 1567
    15  UIKit                               0x002af285 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1194
    16  UIKit                               0x002af4ed -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 201
    17  Foundation                          0x00cb95b3 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 380
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0156d376 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0156ce06 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01554a82 __CFRunLoopRun + 1810
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01553f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01553e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0260f7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0260f668 GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x001ffffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    26  ToDoTasks                           0x00001fad main + 141
    27  ToDoTasks                           0x00001ed5 start + 53
)
2013-07-05 18:00:51.452 ToDoTasks[30968:c07] ended
```

Comment: Try outputing `timeRemaining` (`NSLog(@"timer works %@", timeRemaining);`). I am guessing that your time difference just doesn't change sometimes.

Comment: oh snap you are right LOL. what should i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `date1` a property and do

```
self.date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[testTask timeInterval] sinceDate:now];
```

inside `viewDidLoad`. That way your time difference will actually decrease.

Edit from below:

Don't make your `now` date a property method, put it back in your `timerAction` from your first edit.

Edit2:

change your workflow in `viewDidLoad`. First set `self.date1`, THEN schedule the timer.

Comment: I got the weirdest error. It sounds like Apple is mocking me LOL:
"-[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: toDate cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil toDate?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
"

Comment: that means that your `toDate` was `nil`. Did you make `date1` a weak property?

Comment: `date1` should be a strong property!

Comment: no :( im still getting these weird errors! (even after i changed it to strong)

Comment: could you update your question above, so that i can see your new code?

Comment: ah you should ONLY put `date1` in `viewDidLoad`. leave `now` in your timer method, and dont make it a property.

Comment: hmm...its still saying i have a nil toDate

Comment: does `components = [gregorianCalendar components ...`  use `self.date1`?? In your updated question i just says `date1`

Comment: just updated the question with what i have. i used self.date1 and still got the error

Comment: does it have to do something with NSLocale or something? idk

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the view repaint to update the value

Like this:

```
    [self.superview setNeedsDisplay];
```

Check this out: [Redrawing a view in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135502/redrawing-a-view-in-ios)

So your problem is that the time interval is not changing, use this :

Where you start save the date:

```
NSDate *then = [NSDate now];//gives you the current time
```

When the action is performed save the next date:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate now];
```

Then get the time interval:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:then];
```

Comment: hmm...superview is not valid in my viewcontroller so I put this:

`[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`

in my timer selector right after 
`timerLabel.text = timeRemaining;`

but still got no results..

Comment: try to do timerLabel.text = timeRemaining; [timerLabel setNeedsDisplay]; and then [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; does that works?