# how to trigger drawrect after rotation for a custom UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How does one trigger a redraw (i.e. calling drawrect) after a device rotation for a custom UICollectionView, which has customer UICollectionViewCell and UICollectionViewLayout?

Extra of function from custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), cornerRadius: 50)
        path.lineWidth = 3
        UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
```

Before Rotation

[image: Before rotation]

After Rotation (layout was updated, noting label moved, however oval drawn in drawRect wasn't, and logging shows that "drawRect" wasn't called upon rotation)

[image: After rotation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redrawing a view in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135502/redrawing-a-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `cell.setNeedsDisplay()` after rotation. This will cause the cell's `drawRect:` method to be triggered again.

Comment: From where?. Would it be necessary to loop through all visible cells from my custom layout classes "prepareLayout" function?

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` method triggers the re-drawing of the view on which it is called. When to call, where to call totally depends on individual implementation. Once in your flow you have some data changed which could result in potential UI change then you call this method to reflect data change on UI. And yes, this redraws only the targeted view on which is it called. So, if your data is changed on 2 cells and you want to redraw them then call this on both those cells. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: thanks - interestingly called this (i.e. setNeedsDisplay) on the collectionView (or the parent view housing it) from within the viewController did not work, but accessing the layout and looping through all visible cells from within the viewController does work

Comment: PS I found I had to also place a "setNeedsDisplay" line within the "prepareForReuse" method of my custom UICollectionViewCell, as there would be an issue with some re-use cells being used that were still the wrong size...

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered a much simpler solution to this problem. In your custom cell implementation, set the `contentMode` property (on UIView) to `Redraw`. This will cause `setNeedsDisplay:` to be called automatically when the cells bounds change.